# Read file with multiple end-of-file flags

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a pipe delimited file that was exported from server update. There are approximately 134 million records. I am using excel to import a small number of records (1,000 - 10,000) to explore the data and look for issues before I read the data into other programs (like SAS).

There is an issue in the file at about record 6200, but I am unable to read in the file, as excel will only read in the first 3,200 records. I have found that there are multiple end-of-file marks in the file (the file is from Linux, with windows finding 1A hex coed which marks the end-of-file). Anyone have any idea how to get around this. My current code follows:

```
Sub Test()
file = "c:\user\myfile"
Open file For Input As #1
For i = 1 To 10000
    Line Input #1, dat
    Cells(i, 1) = dat
Next i

Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: does the macro error out, or just stop running?

Comment: Run-time error 62: Input past end of file.

Comment: could you just use **on error resume next**, or another type of error catching.

Comment: Adding the error code was a good idea, it is something that I struggle with. Alas, it did not work. The code did not move to the next line, it stayed stuck on the false eof.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding and replacing the value in the file:

```
Dim CellContent as String
Dim NewCellContent as String
CellContent = 'the line you're bringing in
NewCellContent = (Worksheetfunction.Substitute([your line], chr(26),vbnullstring))

Do Until CellContent = NewCellContent

    CellContent = NewCellContent
    NewCellContent = Worksheetfunction.Substitute(NewCellContent,chr(26),vbnullstring)

Loop
```

Or you could use regex.